# Can not create windows phone project in visual studio 2012

Tags: .net

I have 32 bit OS and VS 2012 Ultimate so I am installing Windows SDK 7.8 update. But after installing I am not able to see Windows phone project type in VS 2012.

Comment: I'm not sure if this applies to the 7.8 SDK, but the windows 8 SDK requires 64 bit OS and virtualization to build wp8 apps in VS. This is because it used Hyper-V to run images of the phones as the emulator.  Perhaps this applies here also? Please check the SDK's requirements.

Comment: So is there any option for 32 bit OS?

Comment: Not for WP8, because it uses real ROM images in a hypervisor as the emulator it needs 64 bit OS. I think WP7 series SDKs used a non hypervisor emulator so that may be an option if you do not need to target WP8.  However given the awesomeness of Hyper-V on your development PC you would probably be better reinstalling a 64bit OS like Windows 8.1